# Cut function not working

Tags: r

I am using the cut function in this way

```
 brks   <- c(0,10^rep(0:15))
> brks
 [1] 0e+00 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05 1e+06 1e+07 1e+08 1e+09 1e+10 1e+11 1e+12 1e+13 1e+14 1e+15

 test <- cut(10^6,breaks=brks,labels=0:15,include.lowest=T)

 but what I get is wrong

>test
[1] 6
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

since brks[6] = 10^4 and not 10^6
```

Can someone help me?

Many thanks

Comment: What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this. `cut` by default closes the intervals on the right, so `10^6` is put into the 7th interval, between `10^5` and `10^6`. Since you labeled these intervals by `labels=0:15`, the 7th interval has label 6. Thus

```
cut(10^6,breaks=brks,labels=0:15,include.lowest=T)
```

equals 6.

On the other hand

```
as.numeric(cut(10^6,breaks=brks,labels=0:15,include.lowest=T))
```

returns 7, the number of interval instead of the label you assigned to it.